# How can I Change the color of a bunch of symbols in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I have a set of flat objects and they are independent, they are all in one single .AI file.

How can I Change the colors of those objects while they are in symbol panel and are not yet in my artboard?

Comment: select them all and change colour?

Comment: I think this is a new question Mr. @Scott What I am asking for is How to change the colors of a bunch of Symbols they are not in my artboard yet. how to change them while they are in their symbol panel.

Comment: I thought you may have been using "Symbol" to be object rather than actual Symbols. FOr actual Symbols, this is a better duplicate link: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8199/illustrator-change-the-colors-of-a-symbol -- Or simply double-click the symbol in the symbol panel and change its color.

Comment: yes I now .. but there is no way to change a 200 symbols at once?!

Comment: No, there's no way to alter multiple symbols at once via the Symbol panel. I've reopened this, but I don't believe what you want is possible.

Comment: If you want to change ALOT of different symbols at once in the palett (instead of all instances of one) you have to try it with (java)script plugins.

Comment: If you assigned a global swatch color to each of your symbols, you could change all of their colors just by editing the swatch. But initially, you'd still need to go through and apply that global swatch to each individual sybmol.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put all symbols in your artboard.
2. Select them all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
3. Press the right mouse button and select *Break link symbol.* Then you can choose the color you want.

Comment: Although this doesn't exactly do what the OP asked, it does seem like the simplest workaround. If you drag them back into a (new) collection of symbols, and the color you assigned was a global one, then in the future you could just update that global color instead.

Comment: i don't know other way to make that right. do you have other idea to make that works?

Comment: Well, if you take your steps and then add my steps (apply global color, convert the images back into symbols), then I think you've mostly accomplished what the OP wanted.  So that's why I've voted your answer up. But we haven't successfully "changed the colors of those objects while they are in symbol panel and are not in my artboard yet". It sounds like that isn't possible yet, without Adobe adding it to the software. Unless you can write a script to do it, like Rockbot mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no "designer" solution to your problem. The way I understand your problem the solution would be Scripting.

This would be a starting point:
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/illustrator_scripting_reference_javascript_cs5.pdf
There should be never versions around.

and maybe check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236210/edit-symbol-in-illustrator-using-javascript